# remove pairs of equal elements from two lists in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am quite new to Sympy (running with Python 3).
Given two lists of integers, in general not of equal lengths and whose elements might repeat, I need to eliminate all pairs of equal elements between the two lists.
For example, given
List_a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 4], List_b=[0, 2, 2, 4]
I shall eliminate the pairs (2,2) and (4,4) and output
List_ar=[1,3,4], List_br=[0,2]
If the two lists are equal I shall get two empty lists as output.
I have been trying to compare the lists element by element ( "for" and "while" loops) and when found equal to delete the pair from both lists. Upon that to repeat the procedure on the reduced lists till no deletion is made.
But lacking of a "goto" control I do not know how to handle the variable length lists.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: This question is about Python in general and does not really have anything to do with SymPy.

Comment: Consider adding a code snippet of what solutions you have tried and why they are not satisfactory. That would help writing an answer suitable for your understanding of the code and the problem.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin: agree, however I need the code to be usable within Sympy

Comment: @LudvigH: I do have some experience in programming, but, alas, in the "old times" (Fortran, Basic) . I added a hint of what I tried to do before resorting to ask for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you convert them to `multiset` you can compare the counts of common keys:

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset
>>> ma = multiset(lista)
>>> mb = multiset(listb)
>>> for k in set(ma) & set(mb):
...    n = min(ma[k],mb[k])
...    ma[k] -= n
...    mb[k] -= n
...
>>> lista = [i for k in ma for i in [k]*ma[k]]
>>> listb = [i for k in mb for i in [k]*mb[k]]
```

You could also treat this like a merge sort but the above is direct.

Comment: Thanks, multiset looks to be a nice and right tool. The code you suggest works nicely on the example, but if the input lists are equal I get .. the same lists, instead of two empty ones. Can you please help to amend for that?

Comment: to my scope, I just need to replace  "n=abs(ma[k]-mb[k])" with "n = min(ma[k],mb[k])", which is the editing I did to your answer

Answer (score 0):

A general Python solution:

```py
def g(a, b):
    def ensure2(xs):
        ys = [list(x) for x in xs]

        if ys == []:
            return [[], []]
        else:
            return ys

    n = min(len(a), len(b))

    c, d = ensure2(
            zip(*
                filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], 
                zip(a, b))))

    return c + a[n:], d + b[n:]

a = [1,2,3,4,4]
b = [0,2,2,4]
c = [0,2,2,4]
d = []

# two different lists
ar, br = g(a, b)
print(ar)  # [1, 3, 4]
print(br)  # [0, 2]

# two identical lists
br, cr = g(b, c)
print(br)  # []
print(cr)  # []

# one empty list
ar, dr = g(a, d)
print(ar)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
print(dr)  # []
```

- Use `zip()` to create the pairs
- Use `filter()` to remove pairs with equal elements
- Use `zip(*...)` to split the remaining pairs back to two lists
- Use `ensure2()` to guard against empty lists
- Use `+ list[n:]` to append excessive elements back to the originally longer list

Comment: This approach is also interesting and straight: thanks for the help. It works good with the example. However, when one of the list shall remain empty, I get the claim     "----> 4     c, d = map(list, 
      5             zip(*
      6                 filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"

Comment: I have added a check to guard against empty lists. It works for empty lists now. Thank you.

Comment: yes, now it is correct: appreciate your help and this alternative solution

Comment: `g([1,2,2,3,4],[0,1,2,4])-->([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 4])` but should be `([2, 3], [0])`

Comment: The OP asked to _pair elements_ between the two lists, then remove those pairs with equal elements. Do not treat the lists as sets, as order and repeated elements are important. @smichr, the way you misunderstand it, I think your answer should be `([3], [0])`.

Comment: One of the 2s does not have a pair in the second list so it should be retained in the first list (see OP example where 4 in a and 2 in b are retained).

Comment: I see what you mean now. But the OP wants to pair element-by-element, not just counting the number of occurrences.

Comment: There's input and output. Everything else is an implementation detail. ;-) OP does not say "remove pairs that are in the same position", just "remove pairs that appear in both lists.